# Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'WebService.asmx.cs'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, webmethod

I am following [this](http://www.magic-dev.com/autocomplete-search.htm) tutorial to create dynamic search results from an SQL server as a user types. It is telling me to create a .asmx file, which is not a format I have ever worked with before. I now have a .asmx and .asmx.cs file. Here is the code I have thus far :

WebService.asmx.cs :

```
public class SearchService : WebService
{
  [WebMethod]
  public searchResult[] Search(string txtSearch)
  {
//Declare collection of searchResult
        List resultList = new List();
        var db = Database.Open("mPlan");
        var result = db.Query("SELECT * from Users where Username like '%" + txtSearch + "%'");
       try
       {
           foreach(var record in result)
            {
               searchResult result = new searchResult();
               result.Username = ["Username"].ToString();
               resultList.Add(result);
           }
           return resultList.ToArray();
       }
       catch
       {
           return null;
       }
  }}
```

WebService.asmx :

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" class="WebService" %>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
[System.Web.Script.Services.GenerateScriptType(typeof(searchResult))]
public class searchResult
{
    public string Title;
    public string img;
    public string href;
}
```

Here is my error message, can anyone help me with this please?

> Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'WebService.asmx.cs'

It highlights line 1 of WebService.asmx as the source of the error.

Comment: `class="WebService.asmx.cs"` should probably be `class="SearchService"`

Comment: Why did you edit your posted code? Your question now makes no sense.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Reverted back,I did not think of that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct class name is "SearchService". You specified a file name.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have now edited my code above. I am still, however, getting the error Could not create type 'SearchService'.

Comment: Because it needs the fully-qualified name of the type.

Comment: Also, are you using a web site "project"? Bad idea. Use a web application project.

Comment: I believe the fully qualified name is SearchService? I have tried Folder.SearchService and this returns the same error. Apologies for the stupid questions, I am very new to this language.

Comment: Again, is this a web site "project"? It would have been created by File->New Web Site instead of File->New Project. It has implications on what the fully-qualified name is.

Comment: Try also adding a new, empty web service. Look to see what the "class" is, in the .asmx file.

Comment: I am actually using WebMatrix at the moment (Visual Studio is not on my computer yet), so I am stuck with a Website project, I believe!

Comment: The main reason to not use Web Site projects is that they are unlike every other kind of project in Visual Studio. When you ask questions about them, you're likely to get answers that make sense for real projects, and which make no sense for web site "projects". Try adding a new service and see what its .asmx file says.

Answer (score 5):

I've come across this error using Visual Studio Development Server when my project output directory was not bin\

One of my DLLs has versions for different platforms (x86, x64), so I created corresponding configurations, and they got by default output directories like this: "bin\x86\Dedug", "bin\x64\Debug". But the Visual Studio Development Server still tried to load binaries from the bin\ folder and of course failed.

I fixed the issue by specifying bin\ output folder in my debug configurations.

Comment: Thanks!!  I just fought this (in my WebServiceHost project) for an embarrassingly long time : ).

Comment: Had the same problem... output was set to /x86/bin.  Changing to /bin fixed it right up.

Answer (score 4):

`class="..."` expects a fully-qualified class-name, not a filename.